# Google Maps Javascript API v3 example doesn't display

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've just visited https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial and clicked on the link 'View example (map-simple.html)' and no map displays.

I also copied their example code to a page on my webserver, and only changed the API key to the one generated for my domain name, and this didn't work either.

Does anyone know if Google is having problems?

Comment: It works for me in Chrome. What browser are you using?  Any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: Do you have JavaScript enabled? Any plugin in your browser that would be blocking stuff?

Comment: If you copy the example (with HTML) and don't change a character, it will work perfectly.  Try not adding the key.  just "...api/js?v=3.exp"

Comment: That's really bizarre because I'm using Chrome on the Google developers site, and just clicked on their example map link. It doesn't work for IE11 or Firefox either. Could it be location related?

Comment: I started checking this because my custom map on www.rvexplorer.co.nz/google-map.cfm stopped displaying - it was working fine a couple of days earlier. It would help to know if others can see it.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? At work? At home?  What javascript errors do you see in the javascript console? Your ["custom map"](http://www.rvexplorer.co.nz/google-map.cfm) works for me also.  What country/continent are you in/on?  Does it work on a different computer?

Comment: I've found that I can get the maps to display if I connect to the net using my mobile phone as a wireless hotspot, but not when using a router to connect to my isp's service. Chrome developer tools are returning net=ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE when attempting to access maps.googleapis.com/maps/api

Comment: To answer you other questions, I work from home and my adsl router has the firewall turned on, but it makes no difference if I turn the firewall off. I'm in New Zealand. It may be a setting on my router that Google maps was previously happy with, or it could be a issue with my isp's network. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be one of Google's servers using a self-signed certificate.

On attempting to access https:\maps.googleapis.com directly using Firefox, I get:

maps.googleapis.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. The certificate is only valid for VMware (Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

There appear to be multiple endpoints for this address, and one of them (at least) has a self-signed certificate.

I've submitted a bug report to Google.